# Два пояснения в скобках, два тире, несчётно запятых, - как быть?

Tags: пунктуация

> Касательно архитектуры, когда упоминают *римское искусство,* то
>   подразумевают под этим и наследие Эллады, которым она воспитана **(на
>   котором оно - искусство - воспитано? или - архитектура? всё одно: на которой)**, и арку,
>   свод и купол – как важнейшие самобытные элементы этой архитектуры (мы
>   пользуемся ими до сих пор), масштаб построек, и отношение к
>   пространству тоже показательно (для Древней Греции его будто и не
>   существует) – для *римского искусства* всегда важен интерьер, это
>   искусство отношения к *территории судьбы*.

Курсив автора, п/ж от меня, недоумевающей.

Если отвлечься от моего обращения к автору (болд), может, всё замечательно читается?

Но с запятыми явное безобразие: я не могу их сгруппировать!

Comment: Авторский замысел: "архитектура воспитана наследием Эллады". То есть я понимаю так: "касательно архитектуры, под римским искусством подразумевают наследие Эллады, которым [наследием] она [архитектура] воспитана". Лечить не берусь :)

Comment: Змий ты, гриззлик! А автор в тебя поверил...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В качестве варианта:

Касательно архитектуры, когда упоминают римское искусство, 
то подразумевают под этим и наследие Эллады, **на котором оно воспитано,**   и арку, свод и купол – как важнейшие самобытные элементы этой архитектуры (мы пользуемся ими до сих пор),  и масштаб построек.  **Отношение к пространству тоже показательно: для Древней Греции его будто и не существует –   для римского же  искусства всегда важен интерьер как возможность выразить свое  отношение к территории судьбы.**

Comment: Уже едет в Рим, тут моей головы мало. Спасибо!